# Email not sent via Gmail - Username and Password not accepted

Tags: grails, gmail, grails-plugin

I am getting this error while trying to send email via Gmail. Here's the code, in the config.groovy file.

```
mail.MailMessageBuilder Failed to send email
org.springframework.mail.MailAuthenticationException: Authentication failed; nested exception is javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 ca4sm3178528pbd.79 - gsmtp

        at grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder$_sendMessage_closure1.doCall(MailMessageBuilder.groovy:112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at
535 5.7.8 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=14257 ca4sm3178528pbd.79 - gsmtp

        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:843)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:765)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:687)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
        ... 4 more
```

CODE:

```
grails {
    mail {
      host = "smtp.gmail.com"
      port = 465
      username = "yomama@gmail.com"
      password = "TTYUIoiuy78"
      props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
    }
 }
```

I tried the suggested solutions from the link provided.

I signed in and changed my password.
I unlocked captcha DisplayUnlockCaptcha 
I also clicked on `allow less secure apps access the app`

Comment: Try this http://www.rocketideas.com/2012/05/gmail-error-password-not-accepted-from-server-solved/

Answer (score -1):

I followed these steps and i'm not getting any errors and working fine..

1. install the mail plugin for grails using the command

   ```
   grails install-plugin mail 1.0.7
   ```
2. open Config.groovy and append these lines

   ```
    grails {
            mail {
                 host = "smtp.gmail.com"
                 port = 465
                 username = "your gmail id"
                 password = "your password"
                 props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                 "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
                 }
          }
   ```
3. In the action where you want to send the mail use this code

   ```
   sendMail {
          to "recepient address"
          subject "Hello Fred"
          body 'How are you?'
          }
   ```
4. compile your app using

   ```
   grails compile
   ```
5. Run app

Comment: Mine also works, locally, but not on a remote server.